# Img size different in IE and Chrome/Mozilla

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this image tag. The size of image varies in IE and Chrome/Mozilla. It works good in Chrome/Mozilla but I see almost 1000% increase in size of image in IE.

```
<img src="{% static "/static/img/left_arrow.png" %}" alt="prev" height="15" width="15" />
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what does your CSS look like and what are the image's dimensions

Comment: Image dimensions are 256x256. And my css is inlined(the one that I've provided already).

Answer (score 0):

This is to normalize image viewing across browsers ([directly from normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)), as well as scale the images correctly when going one direction or the other.

The last line of that is to fix an IE issue for scaling images.

Put this in your CSS file.

```
img {
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  width: auto\9;
}
```

For inline CSS:

```
<img style="border: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;max-width: 100%;height: auto;width: auto;width: auto\9;" src="{% static "/static/img/left_arrow.png" %}" alt="prev" width="15" height="15" />
```

You shouldn't do this with an image larger than you want to scale down to.  The user will be downloading the full image and then resizing it, wasting bandwidth and CPU for them.  This size image isn't a big deal but just keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple to make the size of the image same in all browsers

***CSS***

```
body
    {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }

.imageclass
           {
           height:15%; /* You can Change this according to you */
           width:15%; /* You can Change this according to you */
           }
```

***HTML***

```
<img src="{% static "/static/img/left_arrow.png" %}" alt="prev" class="imageclass"/>
```

This is because the height and width with percent is executed for the outer tag(div, span, body any). Like There is a div with height 100 than the span inside if having 50% than it will be 50 so this is why i have taken the body as % and the image also as %.

Answer (score 0):

adding "px" might fix your problem.

`<img src="{% static "/static/img/left_arrow.png" %}" alt="prev" height="15px" width="15px" />`